# Disabling fancy animations for heavyweight websites

Tags: google-chrome, browser, javascript, css

I am **currently using a low end laptop with the Chrome browser** and sometimes I stumble upon a **heavyweight website** that I want to visit. (for example: http://www.recalbox.com/).

Chrome on my laptop can't handle the amount of animations / transitions / effects and **crashes** due to a **lack of resources** (RAM & CPU).

I know I can switch to a more lightweight browser that uses a different memory management model (for example Firefox but there are others more lightweight) however that doesn't change the fact that javascript is still being executed and css parsed so in the end animations will be triggered in any browser; unless of course  I disable javascript altogether

What **I am looking for is a function / plugin or maybe a client side script** (GreaseMonkey / TamperMonkey or whatever) **to prevent animations without disabling javascript completely**.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this chrome Extention for that:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stop-animations/gemmknjnneiojfjelmgappppbaneikda?hl=en

OR

you can manually block animation of that site by following these steps:
Click on three dots of google chrome on top right-hand side >> more tools >> developer tools >>click on three dots at right-hand side >> More Tools >> Animations >> now click pause icon